# Tool/Webpage to find fitting license for github project

Tags: open-source

I would like to use a tool or a webpage to find a license for a github project.

As a (python) github project depends on various libraries with their own licenses (like for example BSD, MIT, ...) how do I choose the license for the actual github repository?

Is there a tool or a webpage to answer that question? Or to give a list of possible licenses for my github repo dependent on the used packages?

Comment: this may be more a legal matter-I don't think there is software for this, especially since licenses can be customized per project.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "since licenses can be customized per project."...

Comment: a user can use a license template but modify it to meet their needs. Every BSD license is not necessarily the same ([related question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1527))

Comment: My question is more broader. Or should I ask a question for each of the billions of possible combination?

Comment: My point is this is very complex, most software has dependencies each with its own license, and navigating this correctly (depending on use of your software) should be in the realm of legal experts ([article on github license issues/complexity](https://www.theregister.com/2013/04/18/github_licensing_study/))

Comment: Licenses have some features, like "this and that is allowed" and "this and that is not allowed". And licenses do not change every day, they are around for years. Someone must have been taken all the information in a tool where you just "select" the used licenses and outputs licenses you can use. 

I do not thing every single repo owner has a lawer to find the license of their github repos...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139165/discussion-between-depperm-and-alex).

Comment: Have you checked github for tools like https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder

Answer (score -1):

> How do I choose the license for the actual github repository?

Legally, you can only choose the license for your code that you author. If you have dependencies, do not host that code in your github repo. So the license you have chosen is for just your code.

Use submodules to download the other code. Note somewhere in your project that your project uses code from other repos with different licenses.

> Is there a tool or a webpage to answer that question? Or to give a list of possible licenses for my github repo dependent on the used packages?

@Z Z [found a tool in comments](https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder). I can't address how well this works. I tend to do this step manually by reading each license personally.

An example of how to enumerate the licenses in a safe manner is the FreeBSD [port for cups-filters](https://www.freshports.org/print/cups-filters). The distribution for this package has 8 separate distinct licenses.

> BSD4CLAUSE GPLv2 GPLv2+ GPLv3 GPLv3+ LGPL20 LGPL21+ MIT

Each individual package has the potential to have a different license. All the licenses are shipped with the package but the submodules are downloaded at compile time.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.  Did you read it fully ?

Comment: I did. I suppose you are right, as the true answer is the question is unanswered because it would be impossible for software to detect, understand and resolve human errors (such as listing an incorrect license in GitHub). Or any number of other things a  human needs to be involved to answer on a case by case basis. Make sense?

Comment: So every developer on github will most likely do something wrong? Maybe I can sue them all and get rich!

Comment: How can there be so many software developers on github, creating projects, if the could get in legal trouble very easily? How can that be?

Comment: @RohitGupta I took you sage advice, and refactored to be a more direct / better answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex reworded this answer. I think I did a poor job conveying my concerns, and upon reflection I don't think they are important.